# multi picklist options from another object

Tags: picklist, multi-select

I have an object called categories now I want these all entered categories should be get displayed as an options of multi picklist.

Comment: You want to show values from a custom object in a multi-select picklist or just a picklist ? I assume you want to show the name field from custom object as the picklist in another object. How many records are there in this custom object or the unique values ?

Answer (score 0):

First query all records 
and then add them in `selectoption` list

```
List<selectOption> soList = new List<selectOption>();
for(categorie__c ca : [SELECT ID,Name from categorie__c LIMIT 1000])
         soList.add(new selectOption(ca.Id, ca.name));
```

Now display this list in `apex:selectList` tag

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCategoriey}" multiselect="true" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!soList}"/>
 </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: he is looking for multi select so multi select attribute will be true

Comment: Thank you tushar and hemansu. Is there any way like lookup field for selecting multiple values from other object? Here in my case I am displaying the standard page instead visual-force and currently I have a lookup for categories now I want that to be changed In multi picklist or something like that. Apologies for asking this kind of unconcerned question.

Comment: Yes bennie you are right I want to display around 100 unique categories from another object as an options of multi picklist